# Opaque pointer With Class Constructor

Tags: c++, class

I need to create some variable defined in class source private to that class only. I am not able to move this variable to class header because of some other header file issue. I found this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer and explains how it can achieve,

Here is my class source

```
struct testClass::testStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_2;
    client c_3(io_service_2); // this is another class, getting error here
};

testClass::testClass(): test(new testStruct())
{
// do something
}
```

class header

```
class testClass
{
public:
    testClass();
    ~testClass();

private:
    struct testStruct;               
    testStruct* test;               
};
```

While compile the I am getting the error

```
 error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'io_service_2'
```

Actually client is another class which I previously initialized as global

```
client c_3(io_service_2);
```

Now I cannot use it as global, I need to make it as private to the class, so choose above method.

Note: I cannot define `client c_3` as class variable in class header because of some header issue. How can I resolve this issue?.

Thanks 
Haris

Comment: What a bout a forward declaration? I' under the impression of missing something...

Comment: Sorry, I see you speak about opaque pointers, which is essentially the point.

Comment: Now I having the problem how define a class constructor inside a struct.

Comment: The way how you use opaque pointers seems to be correct, but you problem perhaps  related to you **client** class, that seems to be depended  on the struct you want to make private. Can you provide the source code of your **client** class?

Comment: Actually the issue was class initialization inside struct. I solved it by the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420336/class-constructor-inside-struct Any way thanks for the reply.