# Class constructor Inside Struct

Tags: c++

How can I initialize a class with in a structure with class constructor

Suppose my class can initialize like `client c_3(io_service_2);`

Now when I initialize same way inside a struct

```
struct a{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_2;
    client c_3(io_service_2);
};
```

I am getting the error like

```
error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'io_service_2'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent it to default-initialize the `io_service_2` member, *then* use that to initialize `c_3`, and *both* are members, then a member initialization list is needed

```
struct a
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_2;
    client c_3;

    a() : io_service_2(), c_3(io_service_2) {}
};
```

Note order of member variable declaration in the class is what is important above all else, as that dictates the order of member initialization *regardless* of the order in the actual member initialization list

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. My real issue was as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420182/opaque-pointer-with-class-constructor I hope the solution here will resolve that issue also.